# Function based on conditions will not return value- python

Tags: python

I am new to this, and I am looking for help. I currently am stuck in a program I'm trying to complete. Here it is:

```
def searchStock(stockList, stockPrice, s):
    for i in range(len(stockList)):
        if s == stockList[i]:
            s = stockPrice[i]
        elif s != stockList[i]:
            s = -1
    return s

def mainFun():
    stockList= []
    stockPrice = []
    l = 1
    while l > 0:
        stocks = str(input("Enter the name of the stock:"))
        stockList +=  [stocks]
        if stocks == "done"or stocks == 'done':
            l = l * -1
            stockList.remove("done")
        else:
            price = int(input("Enter the price of the stock:"))
        stockPrice += [price]
        l = l + 1
    print(stockList)
    print(stockPrice)
    s = input("Enter the name of the stock you're looking for:")
    s = searchStock(stockList, stockPrice, s)
```

Every time I run the program to the end, it never returns the variable s for some reason. If i replace return with print, it always prints -1 instead of the stockPrice if its on the list. I cant seem to get it to work. Can someone please help me?

Comment: hint: a loop runs until you either stop it, or it reaches its end.

Comment: Doesn't the loop reach its end once s == stockList[i]? @njzk2

Comment: no, there is no reason for it to.

Comment: I figured i could make it stop by just getting rid of 'elif s!= stockList[i] s = -1' but i need that line there. what else can i do to stop the loop once it has the stockPrice[i] for s? @njzk2

Comment: the keyword for exiting a loop early is `break`. but you don't need that else part, you can just move the `s=-1` before the loop.

Comment: thank you so much. i appreciate it @njzk2

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this print to help you debug:

```
def searchStock(stockList, stockPrice, s):
    output = -1
    for i in range(len(stockList)):
        if s == stockList[i]:
            output = stockPrice[i]
            print i, output, stockList[i], stockPrice[i]
        elif s != stockList[i]:
            output = -1
    return output
```

Also I changed one of your variables, it seems better than modifying your input value and then returning it.